# Django: 2 connections to default DB?

Tags: django, database-connection, django-management-command

In a long-running management command I'd like to have two connections to the same DB. One connection will hold a transaction to lock a certain row (`select for update`) and the other connection will record some processing info. If the process crashes, a new run of the management command can use the processing info to skip/simplify some processing steps, hence the need to record it in a different connection.

How do I go about creating a 2nd connection in the same thread? My first thought was to add a `default2` entry to `DATABASES` with the same connection info as `default` and use `.using("default2")` in one of the queries, but wasn't sure if that would cause issues in Django